# Generation of Dynamic Dropdown list from database in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am facing issue while creating dynamic drop-down list which fetches data from database in laravel 5.1. What rectification is required in below code?

This is controller code snippet:

```
   $date_lists = Salethree::lists('Datetime');

   return \View::make('analytics.dashboard.index')->with('date_lists', $date_lists);
```

This is View code snippet:

```
<div>
<label>Select Date</label>
 {{ Form::select('Date', $date_lists) }}
</div>
```

This is the HTML output format I am getting:

```
 Select Date  <select name="Date"><option value="0">2011-01-31</option>                                                                         <option value="1">2011-02-28</option><option value="2">2011-03-31</option><option value="3">2011-04-30</option><option value="4">2011-05-31</option><option value="5">2011-06-30</option><option value="6">2011-07-31</option><option value="7">2011-08-31</option><option value="8">2011-09-30</option><option value="9">2011-10-31</option><option value="10">2011-11-30</option><option value="11">2011-12-31</option><option value="12">2012-01-31</option><option value="13">2012-02-28</option><option value="14">2012-03-31</option><option value="15">2012-04-30</option><option value="16">2012-05-31</option><option value="17">2012-06-30</option><option value="18">2012-07-31</option><option value="19">2012-08-31</option><option value="20">2012-09-30</option><option value="21">2012-10-31</option><option value="22">2012-11-30</option><option value="23">2012-12-31</option><option value="24">2013-01-31</option><option value="25">2013-02-28</option><option value="26">2013-03-31</option><option value="27">2013-04-30</option><option value="28">2013-05-31</option><option value="29">2013-06-30</option><option value="30">2013-07-31</option><option value="31">2013-08-31</option><option value="32">2013-09-30</option><option value="33">2013-10-31</option><option value="34">2013-11-30</option><option value="35">2013-12-31</option><option value="36">2014-01-31</option><option value="37">2014-02-28</option><option value="38">2014-03-31</option><option value="39">2014-04-30</option><option value="40">2014-05-31</option><option value="41">2014-06-30</option><option value="42">2014-07-31</option><option value="43">2014-08-31</option><option value="44">2014-09-30</option><option value="45">2014-10-31</option><option value="46">2014-11-30</option><option value="47">2014-12-31</option><option value="48">2015-01-31</option><option value="49">2015-02-28</option><option value="50">2015-03-31</option><option value="51">2015-04-30</option><option value="52">2015-05-31</option><option value="53">2015-06-30</option><option value="54">2015-07-31</option><option value="55">2015-08-31</option><option value="56">2015-09-30</option><option value="57">2015-10-31</option><option value="58">2015-11-30</option><option value="59">2015-12-31</option></select>
```

Comment: What output you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change date_lists to:

```
$date_lists = Salethree::lists('Datetime', 'id');
```

This will generate the following code if the date id is 234, for example:

```
<option value="234">2011-01-31</option>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you! :)